# How to find process responsible for a dialog in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, process, task-manager, windows-installer

My Windows 10 occasionally shows a dialog box:

[image: Preparing to install]

I am not sure why is the dialog box shown. It can not be canceled and it disappears only after reboot. I want to find process that shows the dialog box.

Task manager does not show any process (neither process nor detailed view) with name or description containing 'installer', 'msiexec' and something like that.  I tried powershell commands `ps | Select-String -Pattern inst` and `ps | Select-String -Pattern msiexec` and they show nothing.

How can I detect the process that shows the dialog?

Comment: You can use Spy++ If Visual Studio with right packages is installed. For example, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\spyxx_amd64.exe"

Comment: we can use this to find virus also i guess

Comment: Spy++ worked for me. The Answer below did'nt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) you can easily find out which process owns a window (or rather, handle). Just use the crosshair in the toolbar and drag it to the window in question:

[image: Process Explorer]

The object that will be checked is highlighted as you drag the crosshair over it:

[image: Highlighted control]

Once over the desired object, let go of the mouse button. Process Explorer will then select the owner process in its list.

Comment: Just FYI: the responsible process was total commander although I closed the application the totalcmd process was still running. When I killed the process the dialog disappear.

Comment: I have used this tool for most processes, but in my case today, it does not catch the process responsible for a dialog showing "Windows Security" then asking for my credentials.

Comment: Very helpful answer Daniel